# Basic Element binding across template and view route, Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view, routes

I am learning how to use Angular JS effectively. And I think I have an easy to solve issue here but I cant seem to find the right syntax to do what I am looking for.

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app =angular.module('adt', []);

        app.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                .when('/add', {
                    templateUrl: 'add.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/add'
                });
            }]);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.numberCounter = 0;

            $scope.addOne = function(){
                $scope.numberCounter +=1;
            };
        }]);
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="adt" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="" ng-click="addOne()">AddNumber</a>
    {{numberCounter}}
    <br>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

My JavaScript is also included in my HTML in this basic example.

**add.html:**

```
ADDD
{{numberCounter}}
```

What this simple app does is increment my scope variable `numberCounter` every time my link called add number is clicked. The number counter works in my main template view, but with view routing(in the view called `add.html`) the number counter is not updating on click. However the view `add.html` will update the number if I manually set the number in the script. What I am I missing here? How can I get both the numbers to update? Let me know if my question isn't clear.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: probably it's better to create a plunker/codepen/etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `html` code. You should not include `ng-view` inside a controller (You have added `MainCtrl` to `<body>` in your case).

Change it to the following,

```
<body ng-app="adt">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

And in your `add.html` must be as follows,

```
<a href="#" ng-click="addOne()">AddNumber</a>
{{numberCounter}}
```

What Angular does is, it populates the `<div>` with the attribute `ng-view` with the content of the `html` file configured through your `$routeProvider` (in your case `add.html`) and also loads the corresponding controller (in your case `MainCtrl`).

**Eidt:**

If you need that `addNumber()` functionality across all views, you can add it to `$rootScope` or you can have another div before `ng-view` with this. The second approach is what I feel is best suited for you.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="adt">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl>
        <a href="#" ng-click="addOne()">AddNumber</a>
        {{numberCounter}}
    </div>

    <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

I haven't tested this code but it should mostly work. So please feel free to comment any issues.

Comment: Thanks for replying Chinni I appreciate the help. It seems your solution is to put my AddNumber link/button into my add.html. But I need the link to be in the main view so it is accessible when different views are routed. This is just a really simplified version of what I am working with and in the future this would have more views.

Comment: I don't know why you want to have that. But I've edited my code. Please check it.